Use ConnectionStrings from System.Configuration in .NET Framework 461 Azure Function App
I want to access Connection String in my azure function app
Code something like this:
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
namespace GetData
{
    public static class UpdateTable
    {
        [FunctionName("UpdateTable")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */10 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)

updateTable(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KEY"].ConnectionString)
    }
}
//something like this.


Library used: System.Configuration
Please help me find a way such that I do not need to make any changes in my code and I can access the values using ConfigurationManager only.

Can you share your complete code in the question?

Please check updated the code.

Try This
[FunctionName("UpdateTable")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KEY"].ConnectionString;
        log.Info($"Connection string retrieved: {connectionString}");

        // Use the connectionString variable in your code to connect to your database or other service.
        // Example: SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

